# Cor do ícone - Toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Como faço para deixar a cor do ícone, em API's menores que a 21, também da cor branca? Na 21 funciona ok, porém abaixo como por exemplo a 16, fica preto.

Fiz dessa forma:

Toolbar

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolvi seguindo o que diz nesses dois links abaixo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762511/overflow-icon-color-in-api-21
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693288/android-studio-1-5-1-could-not-find-property-vectordrawables

Acrescentei no build.gradle as seguinte informações:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
        **generatedDensities = []**
    }
    // Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
    aaptOptions {
        **additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"**
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Eu estou usando a versão do AppCompat v23.2.0, portanto para permitir drawables vetoriais utilizei as configurações acima sinalizadas com ** no arquivo gradle e resolveu.

Para quem está usando Gradle 2.0+, este envolve a adição da linha `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` no seu DefaultConfig no arquivo build.gradle.

Comment: Valeu pelo codigo funcionou perfeitamente.